# show friends data inside accordion tab Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I´m building an app were users can compare their data to friends data.

I managed to make it work by directing the users to a specific compare page (see below)

But now I'm changing the look and I want the "compare page" to open inside the accordion tab.

So... this is the code for the friendslist it's located in the `users/show.html.erb`, there current user can compare his data to friends data.

```
  <ul>
           <% @user.friendships.each do |friendship| %>
           <li>
            <%= link_to user_profile_path(friendship.friend), :method => :get do %>
              <%= friendship.friend.profile.name %>
              (<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span> <%= link_to "Destroy Friendship", friendship, :method => :delete %>)</li>
              <li>
              <%= link_to friendship do %>  

              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> <%= link_to 'Send Messages', new_message_path(to: friendship.friend.id) %> </li>
              <li>
              <%= link_to friendship do %>

             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>  <%= link_to 'Compare', compare_friends_path(to: friendship.friend.id)%></li>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <% end %>

        </li>
         </ul>
```

and the compare_friends_path

```
<div class="row">

<%= render 'users/shared/paper_compare' %>  

<%= render 'users/shared/electro_compare' %>     

<%= render 'users/shared/hwater_compare' %>  

<%= render 'users/shared/cleaning_compare'  %>

<%= render 'users/shared/travel_compare'    %>

</div>
```

and here is the code for one of the partials...in this case the `electro_compare.html.erb`... all the partials are basically the same as in they all have logic to compare different data.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 well">
<h3>Compare Electricity</h3>
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <table class="table table-hover table-box-compare ">
            <thead>
                <th>compare -Electricity</th>
                <th><%= @user.profile.name %></th>
                <th><%= current_user.profile.name %></th><br>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Electricity</td>
                    <td><strong><%= @electro_total_user %> kwst </strong></td>
                    <td><strong><%= @electro_total %> kwst </strong></td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>kwst á hvert stöðugildi</td>
                    <td> <strong><%= @electro_total_per_capita_user %> kwst </strong></td>
                    <td><strong><%= @electro_total_per_capita %> kwst </strong></td>
               </tr>    
                    <br>
                <tr>
                    <td> kwst. f hvert stöðugildi</td>
                    <td> <strong><%= @electro_total_per_m2_user %> kwst/fm. </strong></td>
                    <td> <strong><%= @electro_total_per_m2 %> kwst/fm. </strong></td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    Rafmagnsnotkun Samanburður við <%= @user.profile.name %>
                        <%= bar_chart [
                            {name: "Rafmagnsnotkun #{@user.profile.name}", data: @electro_total_user, 'interpolateNulls':true},
                            {name: "Rafmagn á hvert stöðugildi #{@user.profile.name}", data: @electro_total_per_capita_user, 'interpolateNulls':true},
                            {name: "Rafmagnsnotkun #{current_user.profile.name}", data: @electro_total, 'interpolateNulls':true},
                            {name: "Rafmagn á hvert stöðugildi #{current_user.profile.name}", data: @electro_total_per_capita, 'interpolateNulls':true} ] %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController




def index
    @users = User.all
@users = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)


end

def create

end


def show
  # @user = current_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = User.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
  #@electro_total = current_user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst) 
  @paper = current_user.papers.build
  @electro = current_user.electros.build
  @hwater = current_user.hwaters.build
  @cleaning = current_user.cleanings.build
  @transport = current_user.transports.build

  @papers = current_user.papers


end

def compare
    if current_user.profile
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])
    #@#users = User.friendships.friend(params[:id])
@user = User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]

    @paper_weight_total_user = @user.papers.sum(:paper_weight) 
    @paper_weight_per_capita_user = @user.papers.sum(:paper_weight) / (@user.profile.staff) 
    @env_paper_weight_user = @user.papers.sum(:env_paper_weight)
    @env_paper_ratio_user = (@env_paper_weight_user / @paper_weight_total_user) * 100   

    @paper_tree_ratio_user = (@user.papers.sum(:paper_weight) / 1000) *15 
    @paper_tree_co2_rescue_user = @paper_tree_ratio_user * (0.492)

    #Rafmagn  
       @electro_total_user = @user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst)
       @electro_total_per_capita_user = @user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst) / @user.profile.staff 
       @electro_total_per_m2_user = @user.electros.sum(:electricity_kwst) / @user.profile.building_size
    #HotWater    
      @hwater_total_m3_user = @user.hwaters.sum(:hot_water_cubic_meter) 
       @hwater_total_m3_per_capita_user = @user.hwaters.sum(:hot_water_cubic_meter) /@user.profile.staff
       @hwater_m3_m2_ratio_user = @user.hwaters.sum(:hot_water_cubic_meter) / @user.profile.building_size   

    #Ræsting
       @cleaning_total_user = @user.cleanings.sum(:cleaning_liter)
       @cleaning_staff_ratio_user = @user.cleanings.sum(:cleaning_liter) / @user.profile.staff
       @cleaning_building_ratio_user = @user.cleanings.sum(:cleaning_liter) / @user.profile.building_size   

    #Ferðalog-bilar
       @transport_co2_km_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_km) * (0.1404)
       @transport_co2_km_staff_ratio_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_km) * (0.1404) / @user.profile.staff
       @transport_km_staff_ratio_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_km) / @user.profile.staff
       @transport_km_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_km)
    #Ferðalog-flug
      @transport_flight_co2_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_flight_km) * (0.1722)   
      @transport_flight_co2_staff_ratio_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_flight_km) * (0.1722) / @user.profile.staff
      @transport_flight_km_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_flight_km) 
      @transport_flight_km_staff_ratio_user = @user.transports.sum(:transport_flight_km) / @user.profile.staff

    #Co2 vegna ferðalaga
      @co2_due_to_transport_user = (@transport_flight_co2 + @transport_co2_km) / 1000

      @tree_count_rescue_user = @co2_due_to_transport * 492    
else
    redirect_to user_path
end
end




end
```

And then there is the code for the tabs.... I have an Accordion that opens the tabs.... When tab#10 is opened I want to be able to display the code in the `compare.html.erb` in tab 10. I copied the code to a partial called `compare_users.html.erb` but it is not working.

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                    <%= render 'conversations/msg_part' %>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                    <%= render 'users/shared/users_find' %>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                    <%= render 'users/shared/friends' %>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                    <%= render 'pages/partials/paper_part' %>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
                     <div class="electro">
                      <%= render 'pages/partials/electro_part' %>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
                    <h1>Tab6</h1>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab7">
                     <div class="hwater">
                      <%= render 'pages/partials/hwater_part' %>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab8">
                    <h1>Tab8</h1>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab9">
                    <h1>Tab9</h1>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab10">
                    <%= render 'users/shared/compare_users' %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I´m feeling a bit lost here. Can Anyone direct me to the right path?

Answer (score 0):

First off, rails partials need to have an underscore so your partial should be `_compare_users.html.erb`.

You'll also need to move all that controller code into your show method.

It should work then.

You have a pretty large controller and you may want to think about using a presenter to clean it up a bit.

Hope this gets you going!

Happiness,
Sean